# Opening Chromium from Script

Tags: python, chromium, python-webbrowser

I am having trouble. I can open chromium-browser, from python 3 IDLE, but it doesn't seem to work in script.... the following code will complete without errors but the browser will not open, wether i use ".open, .open_new, .open_new_tab" etc.

Any feedback would be much appreciated.

```
import os
from time import sleep
import webbrowser

def search():

  #new browser object
 chrome = webbrowser.get('chromium-browser')
  #search engine startpoint
 google = chrome.open_new("https://www.google.com")

if __name__ == "__main__":
 sleep(0.5)
 search()
 sleep(1)
```

Comment: On my Linux Mint, your code works in both Python 2 and Python 3

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up having to set chromium-browser as default in a few different places. The script now runs smoothly when executed from the terminal

Answer (score 0):

The browser is not opening because, Chromium browser isn't your default browser.

Either manually set Chromium browser as default browser, and directly run `webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/')`

Or

You can do it by specifying the file path to `webbrowser.get()` if browser is not set as default browser.

For opening Chromium browser, enter the file path of the chromium browser.

```
import os
from time import sleep
import webbrowser

def search():
# Chromium browser location, below location is for my PC, 
# you have to enter the file location for your PC
chrome = webbrowser.get('"C:\Users\singh\AppData\Local\Chromium\Application\chrome.exe" %s')
google = chrome.open_new("https://www.google.com")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sleep(0.5)
    search()
    sleep(1)
```

This will open the google search engine on Chromium browser if you want to open URL by the non-default browser.

Hope it helped you.